# rename specific lines in a text file with sed

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
>alks|keep1|aoiuor|lskdjf
ldkfj
alksj
asdflkj
>jhoj_kl|keep2|kjghoij|adfjl
aldskj
alskj
alsdkj
```

I would like to edit just the lines starting with `>`, ideally in-place, to get a file:

```
>keep1
ldkfj
alksj
asdflkj
>keep2
aldskj
alskj
alsdkj
```

I know that in principle this is achievable with various combinations of sed/awk/cut, but I haven't been able to figure out the right combination. Ideally it should be fast - the file has many millions of lines, and many of the lines are also very long.

Key things about the lines I want to edit:

- Always start with `>`
- The bit I want to keep is always between the first and second pipe symbol `|` (hence thinking `cut` is going to help
- The bit I want to keep has alphanumeric symbols and sometimes underscores. The rest of the string on the same line can have any symbols

## What I've tried that seems helpful

(Most of my sed attempts are pure garbage)

```
cut -d '|' -f 2  test.txt
```

Gets me the bit of the string that I want, and it keeps the other lines too. So it's close, but (of course) it doesn't preserve the initial `>` on the lines where `cut` applies, so it's missing a crucial part of the solution.

Comment: Please add your efforts in form of code, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: Good point. My efforts are pretty poor - I get close, but no cigar I suspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed`:

```sh
sed -E '/^>/ s/^[^|]+\|([^|]+).*/>\1/'
```

- `/^>/` to select lines starting with `>`, not strictly necessary for given sample but sometimes this provides faster result than using `s` alone
- `^[^|]+\|` this will match non `|` characters from the start of line
- `([^|]+)` capture the second field
- `.*` rest of the line
- `>\1` replacement string where `\1` will have the contents of `([^|]+)`

If your input has only ASCII character, this would give you much faster results:

```sh
LC_ALL=C sed -E '/^>/ s/^[^|]+\|([^|]+).*/>\1/'
```

**Timing**

- Checking the timing results by creating a huge file from given input sample, `awk` is much faster and `mawk` is even faster
- However, OP reports that the `sed` solution is faster for the actual data

Comment: Appears to work perfectly. Thanks! If there is any chance you could provide some details on what the sed command is doing, that would help me (and others) learn too. I can appreciate some of it, but not all!

Comment: trying it on my specific example (which is huge) your base-sed is faster than the awk solution. Both work though.

Comment: Good to know, I guess the nature of the input affects which solution is more helpful. But I do hope you tried using `LC_ALL=C` for both `sed/awk` solutions as well as trying `mawk` if possible.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, you could simply try following. In this code, we are setting field separator as `|` for all the lines of Input_file then in main program checking if line starts from `>` then print 2nd field else print the complete line.

```
awk -F'|' '/^>/{print ">"$2;next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F'|' '     ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as | here.
/^>/{           ##Checking condition if line starts from > then do following.
  print ">"$2   ##Printing 2nd field of current line here.
  next          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1               ##Will print current line.
' Input_file    ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Yup - works great now! And thanks for the really great explanation too. Learning a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following `awk` command:

```sh
awk  -F\| '/^>/{print ">"$2} !/^>/{print}' file
# Inplace replacement with gawk (GNU awk)
gawk -i inplace  -F\| '/^>/{print ">"$2} !/^>/{print}' file
# "Inline-like" replacement with any awk
awk -F\| '/^>/{print ">"$2} !/^>/{print}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Here,

- `-F\|` - sets the field separator to a `|` char
- `/^>/` is the condition: if line starts with `<` (and `!/^>/` means the opposite)
- `{print ">"$2}` prints the Field 2 value with a `>` char prepended to it
- `{print}` simply prints the full line.

Note that since `!/^>/{print}` can be reduced to `!/^>/` as `print` is the default action.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/aI667j):

```sh
s='>alks|keep1|aoiuor|lskdjf
ldkfj
alksj
asdflkj
>jhoj_kl|keep2|kjghoij|adfjl
aldskj
alskj
alsdkj'
awk  -F\| '/^>/{print ">"$2} !/^>/{print}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
>keep1
ldkfj
alksj
asdflkj
>keep2
aldskj
alskj
alsdkj
```